# How to cache query data per request

Tags: python, django

I have a decorator that fetches some data from DB and modifies response context data. This decorator is applied to several views, the problem is that every time the decorator function is being executed it makes the DB query again.
I would like to cache the result of a DB only per request, on page refresh/new request I would like to fetch data again.

views.py

```
def set_data():

  def wrap(request):
   # fetching data from db
   data = get_some_data_from_db()
   response = view(request)
   response.context_data["data"] = data
   return response.render()

 return wrap


@set_data
def view1(request):
  context = {...}
  return TemplateResponse(request, "template1.httml", context)

@set_data
def view2(request):
  context = {...}
  return TemplateResponse(request, "template2.httml", context)
```

I've tried to use [django-request-cache](https://github.com/anexia-it/django-request-cache) library, but this doesn't solve this problem.

ANy idea how can i achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by per request? Is there any difference between what you mean and just evaluating the query once per call of the view? 

Also, your decorator seems kind of dysfunctional. `view` and `wrap` don't seem to be defined.

Why do you need a decorator for what you want to do?


If it's about inheritance, have you thought about using [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/class-based-views/) instead?

Comment: "evaluating the query once per call of the view" - Yes that is exactly what I want. Basically, the decorator adds additional data to the context, it's just a quick example.  The project is using function-based views, so class-based views are not an option. Maybe this can be achieved without decorators

Comment: Do you need the data anywhere else than the template?

Comment: No, only in template but in many views that are defined in the same file

Comment: Why not call `get_some_data_from_db` in the view, when initializing `context`?

Comment: if I will make a single DB query at the top of the `views.py` file, it will not be executed after page refresh, only in the first run. Defining in the view function itself, will require making query in each view that requires the data from db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244345/discussion-between-smoenig-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru%20cache%20python#functools.lru_cache):

```py
from functools import lru_cache

# definition of get_some_data_from_db
@lru_cache(max_size=None)
def get_some_data_from_db():
    # get from db code here...

def view1(request):
    context = {
        # returns cached result
        'data': get_some_data_from_db()  
    }
    # ...
    return TemplateResponse(request, "template1.html", context)


def view2(request):
    context = {
        # returns cached result
        'data': get_some_data_from_db()  
    }
    # ...
    return TemplateResponse(request, "template2.html", context)

def view_that_handles_form_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = MyFormClass(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           # save input
           form.save()
           # clear the cache 
           get_some_data_from_db.cache_clear()
           context = {
              'form': form,
              'data': get_some_data_from_db(),  # fills cache with new result
           }
    return TemplateResponse(request, "form_template.html", context)
```